# Iterate on map with multielements

Tags: java

I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Second {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, String>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("title", "title" + i);
            map.put("text", "text" + i);
            listOfMap.add(map);
        }

        for(Entry<String, HashMap> entry : listOfMap.entrySet()) {

        }

    }

}
```

from: [Multi array/object with Java same as in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435535/multi-array-object-with-java-same-as-in-php/25435564)

but how can i iterate this? I would like show element with System.out.println, but in my code I have error:

```
The method entrySet() is undefined for the type List <Map<String,String>>
```

Then I would like to see the results this way:

```
title0
text0
title1
text1
title2
text2
...
title9
text9
```

with System.out.println.

Comment: This would be significantly easier if you used a proper class instead of a `Map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate first over the list and then over each map :

```
for (Map<String, String> map : listOfMap) {
   for(Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println(entry.getKey());
     System.out.println(entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

Comment: This return me error: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map.Entry<String,String> to Map.Entry<String,HashMap>

Comment: @peksak Sorry, I had a typo. Fixed now.